# invitation link for new project returning 404

Tags: gitlab, repository, gitlab-ci

I received an invitation to participate in a project in my email that is linked to my account but I can't access it because the link in the email is giving me the 404 error, how can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Sometimes project invites can expire, leading to the join link returning a 404. Double check if there is a deadline to accept the invite in the original email.

Answer (score 0):

Invites can expire, so the easiest way to ensure this sort of thing doesn't happen:

1. Register an account. Note: On a self-managed instance, you may need an admin to create the account for you.
2. When registering, make sure to use the same email address you received the invite.
3. Confirm your account if required.
4. Sign in.
5. Try visiting the link again.

The idea is that when someone invites you, it will send you an email if you don't have an existing account to join. After creating the account, if the email matches, GitLab should automatically move you from the "invited" list to the "members" list.